# Google Sheets QUERY most recent unique entries

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to use the QUERY function on a list of Google Form responses to only display the most recent of unique entries(based on the key Student ID).

```
A = Timestamp Column 
C = Student ID Column
```

Using:

```
select max(A)
group by C
```

I was able to get the right entries, but only one column for each(**I want all the data, the whole row, from the right entries**)

So I tried using:

```
select max(A),B,C,D,E,F,G,H 
group by C
```

But this gives an error

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGGB

I am new to databases, first time using QUERY. Sorry if this is confusing, but maybe the sheet makes more sense:
[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1QWNV3IrMKqhhauF32y4HKEi2ktGJXQI9S3JZphqMw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Chris' contribution and using QUERY():

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(query({row(Raw!A:A),sort(Raw!A:J)},
"select max(Col1) where Col4 is not null group by Col4 label max(Col1)''",0),
{row(Raw!A:A),sort(Raw!A:J)},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},1))
```

Comment: Thank you JPV! This looks like the best we can do with the QUERY function. I was hoping that I missed something obvious and that the solution would be elegant, but oh well. I looked into using a natural join to solve this with a 2 part solution, but it looks like Google sheets can't do that either!

Answer (score 2):

Does this formula work as you want:

`={Raw!A1:J1;FILTER(Raw!A2:J,MMULT((Raw!C2:C=TRANSPOSE(Raw!C2:C))*(Raw!A2:A<TRANSPOSE(Raw!A2:A)),SIGN(ROW(Raw!A2:A)))=0)}`

Comment: Thank you! Your formula gives me the output I was looking for. It seems reasonable to the QUERY function should be able to do the same thing but there must be something I am missing. Maybe Google's QUERY is just not as functional as other Query languages.