# Return cell content based on max value of other column in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, max, match, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have a table with dynamic cells that count the number of occurrences in a feed from Google Forms. At the left, in Column A there are names of items, and the columns at the right count how many times they are listed in the responses from the forms, so this values change as more responses are added. I am trying to make a report that mentions which item had the most instances per column.

The formula I used initially works:
`=INDEX(INDIRECT("A$3:A$6"), 1, MATCH(MAX(B3:B6), B3:B6, 0))`

But when I move it to count on other columns it gives a #NUM error (value 4 of the parameter 3 is out of range), like:
`=INDEX(INDIRECT("A$3:A$6"), 1, MATCH(MAX(E3:E6), E3:E6, 0))` (even if I change the "1" or the "0" on the formula to match the column number the error persists)

I also found the problem of 2 rows having the same value...or all of them not having data yet and all are "0".

Can anyone see where exactly is the error or have an idea on how to deal with repeated values? (I considered using an IF to name all repeated values unless they are 0, in which case it could display a 'none found' message, but I'm not sure how to implement it.)

I checked these:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59293/find-cell-with-highest-value-of-a-cell-range
- [Google Sheets: selecting cell values based on another cell MAX values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395762/google-sheets-selecting-cell-values-based-on-another-cell-max-values)

**Example sheet** (Tab1 is data and tab2 is where the formulas are. The ones of this question are in row 9 with 2 possible formulas I tried) is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h8_K7nb82hJkDsmUpn6iSkZXhnYEo1NRC2LmRKochgw/edit?usp=sharing .

I tried 2 formulas:

*Formula 1* (B9 - It gives the  **#NUM!** error):

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A$3:A$6"), 1, MATCH(MAX(B3:B6), B3:B6, 0))
```

*Formula 2* (C9- Gives  **#ERROR!**):

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A$3:A$6"), 1, IF(C3:C6>0,"MATCH(MAX(C3:C6), C3:C6, "0","NO VALUES"))
```

The second formula was supposed to fix the 0 value problem by only comparing if the values are >0, else show "NO VALUES" message.

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I added the link and the 2 formulas I tried along the errors they give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

paste in **B9** and drag to the right:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(MAX(B3:B6), B1:B6, 0))
```

[image]

---

for **C9** you can use:

```
=IFNA(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(IF(MAX(C3:C6)<>0, MAX(C3:C6), "♥") , C1:C6, 0)), "no values")
```

Comment: I have  a doubt about mixing both formulas so that it still throws a message if values =0; also, there are more tables below and if I drag the second formula there's **#REF!** error that would override lower cells (there are other tables below). So I was trying something like: `=If(INDIRECT("A$3:A$6"&MATCH(MAX(H3:H6)), H3:H6, 0), "no values") `

Comment: did you check: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h8_K7nb82hJkDsmUpn6iSkZXhnYEo1NRC2LmRKochgw/edit#gid=1806562546 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it gets weird when I place it on another sheet because there are multiple tables around the tab, not only down but also up and there is that **#REF!** thing saying that the answer would overwrite another cell down in the same column (for the ones <> than all 0s). Curiously, all different rows. Any idea why?

Comment: can you share that sheet?

Comment: I restarted and it's working... but a column about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58564930/counta-by-month-and-by-exclusion-in-google-sheets is not working anymore. Anyways, this is working now

Answer (score 0):

```sql
=QUERY(**Range to return**,"SELECT **COLUMN TO RETURN** MATCHES '"&MAX(Range to match)&"' ")
```

if you want more matches:

**AND condition:**

```sql
=QUERY(**Range to return**,"SELECT **COLUMN TO RETURN** MATCHES '"&MAX(Range to match)&"' AND '"&MAX(Range to match)&"' ")
```

**OR condition:**

```sql
=QUERY(**Range to return**,"SELECT **COLUMN TO RETURN** MATCHES '"&MAX(Range to match)&"' OR '"&MAX(Range to match)&"' ")
```