# Show cell content based on max value of other column and if higher than a number in Google Sheet

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm not good with formula so I don't really understand how to modify an existing one ( found here [Return cell content based on max value of other column in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633597/return-cell-content-based-on-max-value-of-other-column-in-google-sheets) ).

That's the one I'm using : `=IFNA(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(IF(MAX(F7:F11)<>0, MAX(F11:42), "♥") , F1:F42, 0)), "no values")`

Here's a copy of the sheet I'm using the formula on, it's on B43 : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HbAbZ5iu-lFk04XkHXheOp6PMJQZhylwm4MsnV6gQLI/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to modify it so it shows the price on an item only if a number associated with it if superior to, say 7000.

I tried to add IF(I11:42)>7000 which I thought was the correct way of doing it but it didn't work and I do not know why.

`=IFNA(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(IF(MAX(F7:F11)<>0, (MAX(F11:42)IF(I11:42)>7000), "♥") , F1:F42, 0)), "no values")`

Some number in column i may not show at all due to a script I'm using to get those numbers, maybe that's the problem ?

If anyone could help me with this I would be really grateful.

Comment: can you add example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: On B81 there's an example of what I would like, the item with the highest number in  profit ( column F ).

I would like to add the amount on market ( column i ) to the formula so a minimum number of item on market is necessary for it to appear as the result. I don't know if I'm clear.

Comment: You need to clean up your formula, there's at least one comma missing in it currently. And the ranges seem off (e.g. max(F7:F11) referring to a load of empty cells). Then you might want to look at the `=MAXIFS` function, that should do it.

Comment: Just like @a-burge has mentioned, can you try first to clean the formula or at least provide an accurate example of how you would like the data to look like/what exactly are you trying to achieve? Since you mentioned this "I would like to modify it so it shows the price on an item only if a number associated with it if superior to", have you tried making use of `FILTER`?

Comment: @a-burge When I remove MAX(F7:F11)<>0, the formula shows "no values" and I do not know why. I tried to use ```MAXIFS``` (B68) and ```FILTER``` (B79)(@ale13) but again I can't understand how to use them properly. I've put an example of what I would like to do in B57.

Comment: I would suggest you go through the documentation of each formula and try to understand what each of them does. Then look at each component individually (put them in separate cells) to find out how they contribute to the final outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B51:F56, I51:I56>7000), 5, 0), 1, 1), "no item")
```

[image]

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: I tried your formula ( slightly modified ) on B43 to see if it works ```=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B11:D42, I11:I42>7000), 3, 0), 1, 1), "no item")```
If I got it right the first condition of ```FILTER``` is what the result will show (item4) and the second is the condition I'm looking for ( a minimum of 7000 items on market ). But it shows an item with less than 7000 items. I don't understand why you used the G column in your formula either. Aren't B F and i the only columns I would need ?

Comment: I had to change the 5 into 7000 to get the formula to work 
```=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B11:F42, I11:I42>7000), 7000, 0), 1, 1), "no item")```
Thank you so much !